# Чем отличается Mime type от File type?

Tags: http

Кроме того, есть ли что-нибудь общее между этими двумя понятиями?

Под File type понимаю расширение файла при сохранении.

Comment: Если с [Mime-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Complete_list_of_MIME_types) в HTTP все более-менее понятно (например, это `Content-type` часть [Http-Header](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2_HTTP)), то что вы имеете в виду под `File type`?

Comment: расширение файла при сохранении...

Comment: Тогда есть. И то и другое предназначено для описания типа содержимого.

Answer (score 2):

`MIME-тип` -- это тип контета в веб-запросах (или ответах). А `file type` (или `file format`) -- это тип файла на уровне операционной системы.

Изначально, MIME -- это Multipurpose Internet Mail Extensions, то есть "многоцелевые расширения интернет-почты", но обычно используется в значении типа веб-контента. Описывается парой выражений: тип и подтип, например, `image/gif`.

И MIME-тип, и формат файла предназначены для предоставления информации о типе контента, что позволяет, например, фильтровать по типу или автоматически определять способ открытия контента: MIME в браузере, а file type -- в операционной системе.

[Здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types) в таблице указано соответствие между некоторыми форматами файлов и MIME-типами, то есть как минимум в некоторых случаях знание MIME-типа позволяет определить тип файла, и наоборот.

Answer (score 0):

Оба, MIME тип и File Тype, описывают формат содержимого документа или файла.
Оба не гарантируют, что действительное содержимое документа или файла соответствуют их описанию.

Больше общего между ними ничего нет.